# Alfresco - Using APIs in a new project

Tags: eclipse, metadata, alfresco

I wanted to know if a new project in eclipse we could import the jar Alfresco and used for example by creating just a jsp with a field of research that would seek a metadata ..?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got it wrong. Alfresco is not library you import to your project. Alfresco is a complete Enterprise Content Management system. For more information visit http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Main_Page

But I wish it was that simple.
I think this way to do it:

1. Install alfresco from scratch... as standalone project.
2. Then develop a webscript using the Alfresco Web Script API, that allows you to create a restful service. Your web script can preform lucene queries to search metadata.
3. Create your jsp form.
4. Then you can use Ajax to get data from your restful service.

Comment: If I may add, you can replace the step 3 with Create your template/preset/whatever and use the components already there.